# 32bit binaries on sharepoint 64bit, An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, sharepoint, 64-bit

I have a lot of sharepoint web parts etc all of which are compiled for any cpu, they run fine on 32bit sharepoint but moving to server 2008 in 64bit causes the following error:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

From my reading they should all work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLLs and vice versa.
2. IIS is a 64-bit process on 64-bit hardware. It's possible to configure individual
   application pools to run 32-bit, but ...
3. Sharepoint is most likely to be running 64-bit.

Therefore, your assemblies and all of their dependent assemblies and DLLs will have to run 64-bit.

Note that .NET assemblies that are marked as "Any CPU" will run as 64-bit on 64-bit hardware. Any native DLLs, however, will need to be compiled natively as 64-bit.

Comment: ok thanks, i will have to explore the code some more and find out if we are using any other DLLs anwhere which may be causing the problem, i thought that the only dependancies were for microsoft.sharepoint dll, and with 64bit sharepoint installed that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Nathan, do you depend on any in-process COM objects? Those need to be 64-bit (point #1 above).

Comment: Nope no COM stuff, and no 64bit dlls except what we have made and they are all compiled for anyCPU and so should work too, most parts work fine but just a few web parts have this error, and if you debug into them they just loop over the render function.

Comment: What was the solution here?  I have a class library that must be build x64.  I also expose this class library through a web application which will run on 64bit hardware.  I cannot build or deploy as I get the following error..

Comment: [BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary64, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix 32bit and 64bit assemblies. Your only option is to rebuild your binaries to x64.

You can run 32bit binaries/libraries on 64bit OS, but again you cannot mix them together.