# Error when trying to validate sharepoint site or deploy solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I set up my windows 7 machine to have sharepoint 2010 running on it, after a lot of struggling, I managed to make it work, but every time I create a new webpart and validate it or try to deploy a solution, I get the following error:

```
*Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://[mysite]. Make Sure that the Site URL is valide, that the SharePoint site is running on the local computer, and that the current user has the necessary permission to access the site.

Additional information:

"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"*
```

I checked and my users is site admin, farm admin and the site is running on my local machine!
I have been struggling with this for 2 days, please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SharePoint 2010 environments are always 64 bit. Make sure the solution you are trying to deploy is *not* compiled to 32 bit.

See: [32bit binaries on sharepoint 64bit, An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132982/32bit-binaries-on-sharepoint-64bit-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a).

Comment: I did check for that and even forced it to deploy as 64 bit and nothing.
Also I can't even validate the site when I try to create a new webpart